# How to use opencv (c++) code in blender?

Tags: c++, opencv, blender

I am working on hand gesture recognition using computer vision for motion simulation. I do not have as good knowledge of python as i have of c++ and hence have programmed an opencv code in c++. Now i want this code to work in a blender.
Please tell me how can i integrate this code in blender.

Answer (score 3):

Without altering blender's source code and [compiling your own custom version](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Building_Blender), you will need to use an addon to use your code within blender. Blender uses python for it's addon system, each [addon is a python module](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/info_tutorial_addon.html#what-is-an-addon). You can use python's [ctypes module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) to call compiled code from a python script.

While normally an addon is written in python it is possible to use or integrate a [compiled C/C++ python module](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/building.html) that can be used in blender. I'm not 100% sure if you can compile the module and add it to blender's addon folder or whether you need to have a folder with the library and a small python script that loads it.

You may want to look at [cython](http://cython.org), it takes python code and turns it into C/C++ code that can be compiled, this may give you a starting point to linking with your code. Have a look at [CubeSurfer](https://github.com/Pyroevil/CubeSurfer) for an example of using cython for a blender addon.

For blender specific help you will find [blender.stackexchange.com](https://blender.stackexchange.com) better.